# Submit Data from partial view to a controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a list of employment records, you can also add an employment record from the same page using a partial view.

Heres employment.cshtml that has a partial view for the records list and a partial view to add a new record which appears in a modal pop up.

```
<h2>Employment Records</h2>

  @{Html.RenderPartial("_employmentlist", Model);}                              

<p>
<a href="#regModal" class="btn btn_b" rel="fancyReg">Add New Record</a>
</p>

<div style="display:none">
    <div id="regModal"> 
              @{Html.RenderPartial("_AddEmployment", new ViewModelEmploymentRecord());}     

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Heres the partial view _AddEmployment.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEmployment, Application"))
{                   
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div class="formEl_a">

<fieldset>
    <legend></legend>

     <div class="sepH_b">

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employerName)
            </div>

         etc....etc....

</fieldset>

</div>
  <p>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn_d" value="Add New Record" />

    </p>


}
```

and heres my Application controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddEmployment(ViewModelEmploymentRecord model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                Add Data.....
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

When compiling the following html is generated for the form:

```
<form action="/Application/Employment?Length=26" method="post">
```

It brings in a length string? and is invoking the Employment controller instead?

Hope all is clear....

**QUESTION ONE:** when I click the submit button from within the partial view it does not go to the controller specified to add the data. Can anyone see where im going wrong?

**QUESTION TWO:** When I get this working I would like to update the employment list with the new record....am I going about this the correct way? Any tips appreciated.

Comment: to question one: if you put something in your catch block in your app. controller, would that provide some insight?

Comment: 1) At the point of using magic strings, I would stop using `Html.BeginForm` and just write the `<form>` tag myself manually. Try that first and see if you can post to your action method. 2) Assuming you mean checking the `ModelState.IsValid` flag? That's only really going to be useful if you're using DataAnnotations.

Comment: When I compile the page the form tag generates ok <form action="/Application/Employment?Length=26" method="post">. It seems to be going to the wrong controller however, employment instead of addEmployment?? Ive updated the main post with this info

Answer (score 9):

Answer 1: First try this and let me know if that hits your controller.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("AddEmployment", "Application", FormMethod.Post))
```

Answer 2: To update the employment list, I would assume you would want to save the model to your database then have your employment list displayed on the same page or a different page calling the data from the DB into the the list or table to be displayed.

**Edit:**
It looks as though your form attributes are not being applied. 
For your employment.cshtml, I personally don't use { } around my @Html statements.
You must not be doing what I stated above because your error occurs only when I write it as

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("AddEmployment, Application", FormMethod.Post))
```

missing those closing quotes is what is causing your problem.

Comment: On a side note. I would not use try catch in a general scenario. Only catch errors you know might happen. then specify it as much as possible. Such as null exception. tho that is a pretty general exception type. If you are worried about uncaught exceptions the best way to deal with these is putting something like ELMAH in place on your site to catch and log these errors.

Comment: It wont let me add the form method....I get the following error:    ****Error 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<ViewModels.ViewModelEmploymentRecord>' does not contain a definition for 'BeginForm' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string)' has some invalid arguments Views\Application\_AddEmployment.cshtml
***

Comment: Please change this code: `("AddEmployment, Application", FormMethod.Post)` to this: `("AddEmployment", "Application", FormMethod.Post)` and you will no longer run into the error and your form should post to the correct controller. *Best Regards*

Comment: ARRRRRRRRGGGGHHH!! Of course! Thanks for the help guys, hitting the controller and saving now. Now to get in to refresh the view without the postback!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery code:

```
window.jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnsave').click(function () {

        var frm = $("form");
        var data = new FormData($("form")[0]);
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Update',
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (er) { }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Controller Code

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Update(Generation obj)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Json("done");
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("error create");
        }
    }
```

Using those code you can post form using jquery and get response in jsonresult

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old Question 
the reason it didn't work for you because your syntax 
Here is your code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEmployment, Application"))
```

the fix

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEmployment", "Application"))
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

you have put `@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEmployment, Application"))` what this is trying to do is invoke a action called `"AddEmployment, Application"` i think you meant `@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEmployment", "Application"))`

Comment: Im trying to invoke the AddEmployment action in the Application Controller. The second part of your answer is the same as what I have?

Comment: Im just seein its not the same after reading the other answer..thanks!

Comment: @Dez79 I was showing you haven't closed the quotes so its just reading as action not as 2 parameters action and controller